# Deploy Kera/Tensorflows model as a package in R to production

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

A little background to understand my problem:

My company uses a private server to put our ML models into production using opencpu. The ML models, which were generated using Caret, are usually written into an R package, that does data preprocessing before passing to the model. The R package, along with opencpu, and the R package dependencies are compiled using Docker into a Docker container, that is then deployed onto the server. I don't understand the deployment process, but that's not my job. My job is to come up with the ML models, create the R package and make sure it works (in our test environment) before it goes to production.

Recently I developed a model using Keras/Tensorflow in R, and want to test this model within our test environment (which is mimics the production environment). This means that I need to include the keras/tensorflow model inside an R package, similar to the Caret version.

I want to know how I can do this without having to install Keras as a dependency. The only point of using Keras is to load the model using the *load_model_hdf5* function, with the prediction being done by the base R *predict* function. Personally I think it is overkill to install such a large package (Keras in R installs Tensorflow, conda and a python environment as well) just to load a model.

This page (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tfdeploy/vignettes/introduction.html) describes methods for deploying Tensorflow models in R, but they only discuss using Rstudio connect, CLoudML and TensorFlow Serving (but this uses gRPC).

Comment: Could you use a combination of a `plumber` REST API (described here https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/deploy/) with the `tfdeploy` package instead of the `keras` package to load the saved model (described in the link you shared)?

Comment: I was now testing with `tfdeploy` to build the package, which works. I know of `plumber`, but haven't given it a try. Thanks for the link, this looks promising